# Google API: Authenticate request with OAuth but without user consent window then request Google data for particular username or user ID

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

While reading this [Implementing OAuth 2.0 Authentication (server side)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#server-side-apps) I noticed the process is probably meant for a scenario where one is creating an app that let's users sign in with their Google credentials and subsequently show their Google+ posts, Youtube videos, etc.

What I need is the ability to fetch Google data based on google user's username or user ID. I do have client_id, client_secret, etc. from Google - and I'm willing to send them along my requests.

Step 1 seems OK. Make a request similar to this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback&
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&
response_type=code&
access_type=offline
```

What would be great after this step is the possibility to just take the code so I can authenticate my request (via Google_Client()->authenticate($_GET['code']); or similar) and then exchange it for the auth_token.

I achieved something similar with Facebook API for PHP for fetching Facebook profile/page public posts - so unlike the sign in with FB process - no user consent is needed nor asked for.

Comment: To start with I would like to recommend the Google API PHP client lib.  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.  Do you know what the users name is and User ID is?  What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: Actually, I am using that client lib - the "authenticate" method in my question is part of it. But I'm unsure how to go about making just (maybe cUrl) request and then get the code value so I can proceed with that (without displaying any user consent screen)...

Comment: You have to request user consent that's the point of Oauth2. The user must give you access to there account.  If you are only accessing your own data (or possibly public data as well depends on what you are doing) then you should be looking at a Service account.

Comment: I've managed to fetch public Facebook posts of any user (based on profile/page username) through OAuth2 by making Http request via cUrl. Onto that URL client id and client secret are appended, which seems enough. Is such a thing possible with Google API?

Comment: Look into https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount there is an example for the service account connection in the client lib

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be it because I found somewhere a class implementing the same thing that I need only for Twitter and the contents of this Service thing resemble the content of that class (creation of headers, etc.)

Comment: Yes service account is a lot like the Twitter API.  Its basically Oauth1.  Oauth2 requires that the user authenticate you so that you can access there data.  Oauth1 you only have access to data owned by the application.

Comment: @DaImTo Your suggestions really helped, I managed to have it running. You can put it into an answer so I can mark it as answered to earn you some credit.
I came back here also to ask you the same thing about LinkedIn API - do they provide an option to act in a similar fashion?

Comment: Cant help you with the LinkedIn API but I Googled it and it seams there is an Oauth1 and Oauth2 version.  You should look at the Oauth1 version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) for this. Accessing the Google APIs using a service account is quite useful. Some times you just want to access your own data and not data owned by other users. In this instance there is no reason to use OAuth2 and prompt a user to give you access to there information, its your information you already have access. This is why we use a service account.

Google Service Account Example with in the PHP client lib can be found here:  [Example](http://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

You don't say exactly which API you are trying to access, and I dislike link only answers. So here is a basic example using the Google Analytics API.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';

/************************************************
  The following 3 values an befound in the setting
  for the application you created on  Google 
  Developers console.
  The Key file should be placed in a location
  that is not accessable from the web. outside of 
  web root.

  In order to access your GA account you must
  Add the Email address as a user at the 
  ACCOUNT Level in the GA admin. 
 ************************************************/
$client_id = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$Email_address = '1046123799103-nk421gjc2v8mlr2qnmmqaak04ntb1dbp@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '629751513db09cd21a941399389f33e5abd633c9-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

// seproate additional scopes with a comma
$scopes ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";  

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $Email_address,
    array($scopes),
    $key
    );

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

I have a tutorial that goes along with that code it can be found here.  [Google Service Account PHP](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/)