# YouTube - Data API v3 Unable to display private videos of my YouTube channel on my website using Google Service Account

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have few private videos on my YouTube channel and i want to put them on my website. Basically i don't want my website users to watch them directly on my YouTube channel. Furthermore i don't want to show consent screen to the users either. I browsed and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663681/google-api-authenticate-request-with-oauth-but-without-user-consent-window-then) example at **stackoverflow** in which **DalmTo** is suggesting someone to use Google Service Account to achieve this. My code works fine with publicly available videos but it does not show the private videos whenever i search the video with it's ID.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("YouTube-Example");
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service_account.json");
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client); 

try{
      $response = $youtube->videos->listVideos(
                  'snippet',
                  array(
                  'id' => 'pW0og1OZurE'    //private video unable to display
                  )); 

      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($response);

} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
   $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
   htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
   $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
   htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}
?>
```

I followed the documentation but i can't figure out why it's not working. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying of private videos is not allowed in Youtube API as [stated in the help guide](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/77272?hl=en).

> Private videos can only be seen by people who have been invited to
> view the video.
>
> Here are some possible reasons why you or somebody you’ve shared the
> video with aren’t able to see a private video:
>
> -Viewers need to have a YouTube account and be signed into it when trying to view the video.
>
> -If the viewer has multiple YouTube accounts, they must be signed into the account which the video has been shared with.
>
> -Since private videos don’t appear on a Channel page, the person will need to use the specific link to the private video. YouTube will send
> them an email with the link once you’ve invited them, but you can also
> send it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here may be your answer:

> The `forMine` parameter indicates that the response should only search within the authorized user's videos. Also, since this request uses the `forMine` parameter, it must also set the type parameter value to video.
>   If you have not uploaded any videos associated with that term, you will not see any items in the API response list.

Source: [Google developers docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it_1)