# Share My Private youtube video to My Application users, by YoutubeDataApi. Or Add My Private Youtube Video to Android Application

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to share Youtube Private Video through YoutubeDataApi. As I have My private video which I want to share with my App User by YoutubeDataApi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube - Data API v3 Unable to display private videos of my YouTube channel on my website using Google Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801170/youtube-data-api-v3-unable-to-display-private-videos-of-my-youtube-channel-on)

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch private videos through Youtube API, [Read the YouTube Docs about this.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/77272?hl=en)
Those videos can only be viewed by users you invite and has an YouTube Account.